# Using liquidfun.js within nw.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nw.js, liquidfun

I am writing an application that uses two components that appear to be conflicting with each other.

liquidfun.js and node.js/NW.js

I am using liquidfun to do a fluid simulation. I am using window.get() in NW.js to set the window zoom level. Each works without the other.

Here is the error when I run both simultaneously.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined      liquidfun.js:3
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function      liquidfun.js:1443
```

I suspect that node has some function property that shared the name "module" with something in the liquidfun library.

How do I prevent NW.js from processing the liquidfun script?

Additional Information:

The pages are being served from a xampp server on the same computer so I have to use "node-remote" to set the zoom level.

EDIT:

HTML that is loaded by nw.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>html5canvas</title>


<script src="libs/liquidfun.js"></script>
<script>
    var gui = require('nw.gui');
    win = gui.Window.get();
    win.zoomLevel =[-10];

</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="2160" height="3840" style="background-color:#B1D1B1"></canvas>

</body>
<script>
    var world = null;
    var gravity = new b2Vec2();
    function init(){

        world = new b2World(gravity);

    }
</script>
```

NW.js Package.json

```
{

    "main": "main.html",
    "name": "Fun Editor",
    "node-remote" : "127.0.0.1"

}
```

The result of this is the module error mentioned in original post.
When node-remote is removed liquid fun reports loading succesfully. There is another error without node-remote

```
UncaughtReferenceError: require is not defined    (program):1
```

Comment: Could you post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to replicate this easier?

Comment: Ok. I'll try. Not 100% sure how I would do that given the complexity though. How would I refer to multiple libraries and such to make the example?

Comment: If I got it right (which might not be the case), you're using liquidfun.js within a page that you load using nw.js, right? If that's the case, post your html and relevant scripts.

Comment: @cviejo That is exactly what I am trying to do. I added the example.

Comment: Oh, i see the problem here. `liquidfun.js` is finding `require` is defined so it assumes it's being loaded as module and expects  `module` and `exports` to be defined too. Will post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that liquidfun first evaluates the evironment it's running on and since `require` is defined, it expects `module` and `exports` to be so as well. As a particularity of nw.js this won't be true. So you need to `require` your library like this instead:

```
<script>
    var lf      = require("./libs/liquidfun.js");
    var world   = null;
    var gravity = new lf.b2Vec2();

    function init(){
        world = new lf.b2World(gravity);
    }
</script>
```

Now, while this will do for almost all cases, won't help on it's own in this case since liquidfun doesn't seem to be exporting the necessary classes (I'm not familiar with this library so there might be a way of doing so). Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715782/how-to-include-liquidfun-physics-engine-with-nodejs), you could just add the necessary exports at the end of the library:

```
module.exports = {
    b2Vec2         : b2Vec2,
    b2BodyDef      : b2BodyDef,
    b2PolygonShape : b2PolygonShape,
    b2FixtureDef   : b2FixtureDef,
    b2World        : b2World,
    b2_dynamicBody : b2_dynamicBody,
    setWorld       : function(_world){ world=_world;   }
};
```

Another way of approaching this (since you need to edit liquidfun.js anyway) would be tricking the library into running in regular web mode. You can accomplish this by replacing this bit in the first line:

```
...process==="object"&&typeof require==="function";...
```

with this:

```
...process==="object"&&false;...
```

You can then use the library as expected:

```
<script src="libs/liquidfun.js"></script>
<script>
    var world   = null;
    var gravity = new b2Vec2();
    function init(){
        world = new b2World(gravity);
    }
</script>
```

Needless to say, both solutions are a bit "hacky" and not quite optimal.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and would prefer to follow that line since the other would require a great deal of editing. It didn't work but is there a way to kill that evaluation for require altogether?

Comment: I tried everything above before posting, both solutions do work. What do you mean with "it didn't work", exactly? what errors did you get?

Comment: The same error as before

    'Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined      liquidfun.js:3
    'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function      liquidfun.js:1443

This is when I change what you recommended.

Comment: If you replaced `typeof require==="function"` with simply `false` in `libs/liquidfun.js` as described above it's literally impossible to get that error again. Just tested it again. Please go through the steps and try it again.

Comment: You were right. I did follow your steps though. NW.js saves a cache in '%localappdata%\' so it wasn't looking at the liquidfun.js that I edited. Thank you sir.